# Отслеживание логов в консоли браузера tumpermankey script

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Redirect NektoMe Chat
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Redirect from /peer to /searching on NektoMe Chat when dialog ends
// @author       Hi
// @match        https://nekto.me/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Listen for console messages
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        if (event.data === 'peerClose FUNCTUON!!!') {
            // Redirect to /searching
            window.location.href = 'https://nekto.me/audiochat#/searching';
        }
    });
})();
```

Простой скрипт который должен был отслеживать в консоли лог о том что соединение закрыто и перенаправлять пользователя на url с поиском.

Не работает при запуске

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19846078/3129992